# Woocommerce - example.com/?v=d21feabed96b is appending to the URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocomerce

When the pages are loading ,its appending values to the URL .

FOR example:

**example.com/?v=d21feabed96b**

Answer (score 2):

Its due to the geolocate option in **Woocommerce -> General -> Default customer location -> Geolocate** .

Change it to no location by default.

[image]